# Strange Assignee names coming from Assignee column in jiraissue table

Tags: jira

I am using Jira backend database to pull some columns for reporting. `Assignee` column in `jiraissue` table stores the Webkey ID/usernames of all the employees. I join this with `cwd_user` to get the full name of the assignee. But I also see some weird values like the ones below. I don't have a clue about how to get the display names of these users. They are not Webkey ID/usernames.

[image]

Any thoughts on what I might be missing?

Comment: I will try app_user table and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app_user table has the current userid in the lower_user_name column

Answer (score 2):

If you're running a recent version of Jira, there was [a GDPR-related change](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/important-gdpr-changes-in-jira-server/#2.-Generating-user-keys-for-new-users) that causes all newly-created users to have a `key` starting with `JIRAUSER` instead of their username. Users can also be anonymized through this feature.

You can get a mapping of `JIRAUSER` keys to usernames through [the JIRA API's Get User endpoint](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/8.16.2/#api/2/user-getUser) -- not sure where to look in the database for this mapping yet.